# Can we copyright a musical chord progression?

Tags: copyright

Can we copyright a musical chord progression?

I've heard it said that musical chord progressions are not protected
if someone writes a new melody over the chords.

Comment: Apparently  not:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pidokakU4I

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways that you could analyze the question, but one of the easiest is to consider that any remotely musical chord progression has already been invented and is now in the public domain.

You could copyright your particular performance of that chord progression, but the underlying composition that you are performing would be in the public domain already.

Comment: Spotify  alone adds about 1M new songs to their catalog. For a 4 chord progression, there  only 13,000 or thereabout possible combinations (depending on how you exactly define it). Most of these sound pretty terrible, so some repetition is unavoidable

Comment: @Hilmar This observation is basically a variant of the notion behind the scènes à faire doctrine https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sc%C3%A8nes_%C3%A0_faire which basically holds that creative elements which are genre conventions cannot be protected by copyright law.